# Returning different JSON objects based on role of currently authenticated user

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

How do I conditionally serve different JSON objects from a Spring (3.1) backend? I am using Spring Security but I don't understand how I can serve different representations of an object?

I am only interested in the security logic, the other things I already have in place.

If a user named `Sylvester` is logged in with the role `admin` then he will recieve a bigger JSON object (more data) then a `Arnold` with the role `user`.

Do I have to use the authentication object see if the user has a particular role? Or are there some annotations or some other magic to do this?

Comment: If your handler method can be called by any role user, then you can't use annotations. Instead, grab the user details, check the roles, and use an if-else to build your response.

Comment: How would you check the roles? Example...

Comment: I don't know the spring security API, but there must be an interface to check the user authorities.

Answer (score 0):

In your logic you need to check current loggedIn user's role, and based on role you can return different response.

Yes you need authentication object, that must be implementing UserDetails interface and should have basic user info including its role/privileges.

Answer (score -1):

This post seems to duplicate [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600425/using-spring-security-in-order-to-display-different-content-for-the-same-url-bas) for the major part. Have a look at it and more precisely at this [blog post](http://blog.mohchi.com/post/32207832404/tighter-spring-mvc-integration-with-spring-securitys), which gives a nice solution, but you will probably have to include or adapt 3rd-party code.